# Mobile App - Twilio Video/Calling inconsistent push notifications

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, twilio, real-time

Currently I am using twilio video for video calls from mobile to mobile. I am using FCM push notifications to start calls. Is there a better way using a real-time way to handle calls between devices. Just looking for better reliability since push notifications can be inconsistent.

Not exactly sure how real-time would work with app in background/closed when starting calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think make it a background service so that it runs unless the user terminates the app

Comment: It would be good to add such suggestions as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

On iOS you can use CallKit to create push notifications that behave like an incoming call. The [Twilio Video iOS Quickstarts](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios) repo has an example [Twilio Video CallKit application](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios/tree/master/VideoCallKitQuickStart) you can look into.

I'm afraid I don't know of a better way to do this with Android though.